# How to assign a value to strings?

Tags: c, enums

All I am doing is assigning these strings to the enumdata type value, and yet it won't work. I have assigned strings to an enum in C . What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum day{monday,tuesday,wednesday};

int main()
{ 
    enum day pres;
    int n,ab;
    scanf("%s",&pres);
    scanf("%d",&ab);
    n=((ab%7)+pres);
    print("%d",n);
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Not reading the book?

Comment: You need to learn first basic about `C`. Good start from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm

Comment: my question is that how to assign a value to the strings for suppose m giving input as monday and ab as 7 the result will be 0 but it is not geting

Comment: `enum`s aren't strings, what you did is more or less equivalent to `const int monday=0,teusday=1,wednesday=2;`. You didn't declare `ab` neither `n`, and there's no such `print` function in the standard library.

Comment: why not directly use `enum` (`n=((ab%7)+monday`);)and why you put string in picture? There nothing about `string` in `C`.

Comment: ... And you are missing #include ...

Comment: Why not have a rethink and reread

Comment: okay then how to assign a some value to the string which we are giving input as string

Comment: @chandubunnyfan have you heard about `sprintf`? ex `sprintf(str,"%d",monday);`. Take `str` as char array.

Comment: Hi welcome to so. Please read through [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

> What am I doing wrong?

The answer is - *everything*. Each, absolutely each line has a mistake or a typo.

`teusday` should be `tuesday`

`void main` should be `int main`

`enum` variable declaration needs semicolon in the end of line

`#include <stdio.h>` is missing  for `scanf`

You can't write strings to enum values at all.

`ab` is not declared

`n` is not declared.

`print` function doesn't exist, `printf` does.

PS. try to learn more theory first before writing the code. Read a good C book - there are many of those

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want to know the code and i too know that silly things i think here code part is main but all are concentrating on normal errors...

Comment: There is no way to do what you want. Use normal C-strings instead of enum-values

Comment: @chandubunnyfan None of the errors sasha.sochka listed are “silly”. They are all real errors and if you don't even want to do the effort of writing a program that is free of “silly” errors, you don't deserve to be helped.

Comment: char date[15]="monday"; by using it will take the string name but not value thats y m asking how?? and  FUZxxl m not complaining about the which have been posted by sasha.sochka

Comment: An error is an error - it is not silly

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum DayOfWeek {
    Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, ErrDOW=-1
};
static const char *nameOfDOW[] = {
    "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"
};

enum DayOfWeek strToDOW(const char *str);

int main(void){ 
    char in_str[16];
    enum  DayOfWeek aDOW;
    int wday, addDay, n;

    printf("Please enter the name day of the week : ");
    scanf(" %15s", in_str);
    if(ErrDOW==(aDOW = strToDOW(in_str))){
        printf("invalid name\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Please enter the number of days to add : ");
    scanf("%d", &addDay);

    n= (aDOW + addDay) % 7;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    printf("%c%s\n", toupper(nameOfDOW[n][0]), nameOfDOW[n]+1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;  
}

enum DayOfWeek strToDOW(const char *str){
    char *s = strlwr(strdup(str));//note : strdup and strlwr are not standard.
    int i, len = strlen(s);
    for(i=Sunday; i<= Saturday; ++i){
        if(3 == len){
            if(strncmp(nameOfDOW[i], s, 3)==0)
                break;
        } else {
            if(strcmp(nameOfDOW[i], s)==0)
                break;
        }
    }
    free(s);
    if(i > Saturday)
        return ErrDOW;
    else
        return i;
}
```